# Media type separator is missing

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs

Please help as I don't know what is wrong here. I have a very simple REST GET service but I keep running into the error below:

```
@GET
@Path("users/{id}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return Response.status(200).entity("getUserById is called, id : " + id).build();
}
```

And the exception I'm seeing is below:

> [ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5000)
>       at [internal classes]
>   Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:401)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Media type separator is missing
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.MediaTypeHeaderProvider.handleMediaTypeWithoutSubtype(MediaTypeHeaderProvider.java:196)
>       ... 1 more

Any idea what is wrong here?  TIA

Comment: I believe you're looking for `@Produces("text/plain")`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textplain

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.  And this issue resolved on its own after I rebuilt my project and restarted it.  I can't tell what caused it.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Just a comment - consider using the [MediaType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) values - i.e. MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN to prevent typos, etc.  Not every one is in there but the commonly used ones are.